# Numpy Module Not Found But is Installed

Tags: numpy, error-handling, pip

I am trying to install the OApackage for python. I am a Mac user and try to install it in the terminal using `pip install OApackage`

However, I get the following error:

```
(myenv) ➜  ~ pip install OApackage    
Collecting OApackage
  Using cached OApackage-2.7.7.tar.gz (1.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [23 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 22, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
      
      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
      
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/annata/myenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Users/annata/myenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/Users/annata/myenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/private/var/folders/pm/2t8wl69546qcmgdmd72vg1zc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-cl92mt72/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "/private/var/folders/pm/2t8wl69546qcmgdmd72vg1zc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-cl92mt72/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/private/var/folders/pm/2t8wl69546qcmgdmd72vg1zc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-cl92mt72/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
        File "/private/var/folders/pm/2t8wl69546qcmgdmd72vg1zc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-cl92mt72/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 24, in <module>
      RuntimeError: numpy cannot be imported. numpy must be installed prior to installing OApackage
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I have tried to use different shells (bash and zsh, conda, VS), I have tried to run it in different environments. I have tried it with different versions of Python (3.8, 3.9, 3.10, 3.11) and different versions of Numpy (for Python 3.8 and 3.9: Numpy==1.19, 1.3, 1.4.1, 1.18.0, 1.18.5) (for Python 3.10 and 3.11: Numpy==1.23.5, 1.24.3)

Does anyone have an idea why this error occurs?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how to resolve this. However, as no solution has been given, I'll leave two questions/checks here (it's the best I can do). 1. Are you sure you have installed all the requirements in the environment? 2. Have you checked if pip's cache is preventing you from using the versions you want?